# Why does the last Menuitem get included in the last submenu although it is outside of it?

Tags: primefaces, menuitem

I added a menuitem to the Primefaces (6) toggleable menu showcase:

```
<p:menu toggleable="true">
 <p:menuitem value="Test" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
    <p:submenu label="Ajax">
        <p:menuitem value="Save" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
        <p:menuitem value="Update" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"/>
    </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="Non-Ajax">
        <p:menuitem value="Delete" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
    </p:submenu>
    <p:submenu label="Navigations">
        <p:menuitem value="External" url="http://www.primefaces.org" icon="ui-icon-home"/>
    </p:submenu>
    <p:menuitem value="Test" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
</p:menu>
```

Why does the last item "Test" get collapsed in the last submenu "Navigations" ? **I expected it to stay outside**, just like the first "Test" menuitem:

[Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hktSV.png)

[Collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrNFK.png)

Comment: Please state your PF version? And look at the rendered htnl

Comment: "Menu is a navigation component with one level of submenus." IMO they should throw an exception when anything other than a `submenu` is used.